# Devise implementation. Admin as a separate table or as a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, theory

May be my question is to theoretical, but I would like to know your opinion on what is the usage of devise as a separate table, or a column in a Users table.

Some basic point would be great to discuss:
1. In what situation would you choose this or the other implementation?
2. What methods does devise add when implementing it as a seperate table?
3. What do you find the easiest way to implement devise, and why?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do 2 or more devise model in each application.

But in many case ['Single Table Inheritance(STI)'](http://therailworld.com/posts/18-Single-Table-Inheritance-with-Rails) might help you a lot.
Is good **if data is not different and have a same behavior**.
It will make you **easy to handle complex data sometimes**.

**But there is create a lot of null column in table when each role is store different data and it have a slower query time**.

If you want to customize much more what is role can do then you [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) with [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) it will help you life easier.

**PS. In real life normalized data is not mean it have a good database design.**

Comment: Good system design answer. Thank you for your opinion.